# "Failed to connect to api.twilio.com port 443: Connection refused" error

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I've disabled SSL Certificate Validation under General Settings because my WordPress site is using http.
But I am still still getting "Failed to connect to api.twilio.com port 443: Connection refused" on live and test credentials."
I've also purge caches on the browser.
I am using the guide from https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/send-sms-wordpress-php-plugin.html.
Does the setting takes time to remove the SSL certification validation or what else could go wrong?

Comment: I've tested it https, it works. Just wondering how to make it work after I've disabled SSL Certificate Validation under General Settings in the Twilio dashboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered by Twilio support "All connections to the Twilio API endpoints must use HTTPS and so if you have no SSL Cert for your Wordpress website it will refuse the request. You will need to get an SSL Certificate for your website in order to call the API endpoints from your Wordpress site/domain. Disabling SSL Certificate Validation setting on Twilio dashboard is for calls from Twilio to your servers, not the other way around."

Comment: Is there any workaround to work with Twilio API from HTTP as I'm testing it out on my localhost?

Comment: I would have suggested making your localhost https and test it. But I don't know whether a self-signed SSL certificate would make it work.